# Finding all objects on which method X is executed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis

Let's assume there are a lot of code blocks like this in my solution:

```
switch (Key)
{
    case "A":
        displayName = "Title1";
        break;
    case "B":
        displayName = "Title2";
        break;
    case "C":
        displayName = "Title3";
        break;

    default:
        throw new NotSupportedException();
}
displayName = displayName.X();
```

Is there a possibility to get all strings in code on which method X can be executed?

Comment: You could use Resharper for finding out all usages of the method `X` in your code.

Comment: The question is a "bit" vauge. You don't need Resharper to find all references to a method, Visual Studio already has that. The answer here would be `displayName`. If you want to find the *string literals* though, you'd have to write your own analyzer that followed references and assignments to variables until it found a string literal. You'd probably have have to write your own code analyzer with Roslyn for this. I doubt any tool would have such a specialized analyzer.

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos ,this seems to be a solution for my problem!